# I have been using Visual Studio Code in my Mac. When I try to compile and run the program, it pops a message as 'Permission denied'

Tags: c

I get 'Permission denied' whenever I try to compile and run a program in Visual Studio code, in my Mac. How do I solve this?

Note the 'permission denied' in this picture
[image]

Comment: I compile and run programs on my Mac all the time, so it can be done.  When you say "Visual Studio code", I assume you meant code that was originally developed under Visual Studio on a Windows machine, and then you moved the `.c` and `.h` files over to your Mac?

Comment: What version of MacOS?  I assume you've installed XCode, but which version?  Are you using the `cc` command to compile, or `make`, or something else?  Can you show us the exact command(s) you're typing, and the exact error messages you get? (Based on your description, I can't tell whether you get "permission denied" when you try to run the compiler to compile your program, or when you try to run your program.)

Comment: @SteveSummit "Visual Studio Code" is a cross-platform IDE from Microsoft. I'm not familiar with how it interacts with build tools, though.

Comment: Where are the file you try to compile? Do you have permission to write in that folder?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? There is **no** other text or information at all in the window that pops up? Show a screen shot of it.

Comment: Are you trying to run the __source file__?! Has the new file that appears after compilation is finished not sparked your interest? Do you know what the `-o film.o` thing does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say something like

```
gcc -o film film.c
```

and then

```
./film
```

`film.c` is your source file.  In the example I've shown, the `-o` flag asks `gcc` to put its output -- the compiled program -- in file `film` (with no conventional suffix).  *That's* the file you want to run.